# finding value of a Nested Square root.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

Let  $ x = {\sqrt{25 -\sqrt{51- \sqrt{25-\sqrt 51.....}}}}$   what is the value of x?

My attempt is to let $x = {\sqrt{25-\sqrt{51-x}}}$
and raised it to be in a polynomial form but I just got equation
$$
x^4-50x^2+x+574=0
$$
which I couldn't solve and I ran out of idea to solve this. Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: I think the method you sketch is optimal.  What equation do you get?

Comment: If the value converges, the equation with $x$ that you wrote is indeed correct.

Comment: i got $\ x^4-50x^2+x+574 =0 $ .

Comment: Yes, that's what I see.  Well, numerically, that has four real roots. It is easy to see that your $x$ must satisfy $0<x<5$ and that determines the value uniquely (though, technically, you should still show convergence).

Comment: It might be unsightly, but there is a general method to solving quartic equations. That said, I'm not sure it's the best method as much as just a brute-force method

Comment: @KhunpolJermsiri, you can solve any 4th degree equation in radicals.

Comment: You may find this [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4-50x%5E2%2Bx%2B574%3D0) useful, the root that follows the constraint $0<x<5$ (as @lulu mentioned) is $x = 4.2619$

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Sturm Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) for $x^4-50x^2+x+574$, it can be shown that there is one root in $[0,5]$.
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sqrt{25-\sqrt{51-x}}=\frac1{2\sqrt{25-\sqrt{51-x}}}\frac1{2\sqrt{51-x}}\tag1
$$
For $x\in[0,5]$, $(1)$ is bounded by
$$
\frac1{4\sqrt{25-\sqrt{51}}\sqrt{46}}=\frac{\sqrt{25+\sqrt{51}}}{4\sqrt{574}\sqrt{46}}\le\sqrt{\frac{33}{422464}}\le\frac1{113}\tag2
$$
Thus, for $x\in[0,5]$, $\sqrt{25-\sqrt{51-x}}$ is a contraction. This means iterations converge to the root of $x^4-50x^2+x+574=0$ in $[0,5]$.

In fact, $10$ iterations, representing $20$ levels of square roots, yields $20$ decimal places of accuracy, since $5\cdot\left(\frac1{113}\right)^{10}=1.47294174\times10^{-20}$:
$$
x=4.2618623097711113752
$$